# Windows authentication & authorization is not working in asp.net core 6 with react application

Tags: reactjs, .net, .net-core, windows-authentication

I am developing a SPA using React with .net-core 6 template. I want to use the Windows authentication. I tried multiple ways suggested by many on the internet. It is working in build which hosted on the IIS. But not working in develoment mode.

I have created the project using this template.[click to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0s4v.png)

1. LauncSettings.json
   [Click to open LaunchSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy1SE.png)

```
      "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:20344",
          "sslPort": 0
        }
      },
      "profiles": {
        "StudentApp3": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5058",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
          }
        },
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

2. SetupProxy.js
   [Click to open SetupProxy.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znGq9.png)

```
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    const { env } = require('process');    
    const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
      env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:20344';    
    const context =  [
        "/weatherforecast",
        "/student",
    ];    
    module.exports = function(app) {
      const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
          target: target,
          secure: false,
      });    
      app.use(appProxy);
    };
```

3. React Fetch Call
   [Click to open Fetch call from react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENPjX.png)

```
    fetch("/student/getstudent", {
                method: "GET",
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    "Connection": 'keep-alive',
                }
            }).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            });
```

4. Controller
   [Click to open Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FIoY.png)

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    namespace StudentApp.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public class StudentController : Controller
        {
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
            [Authorize]
            [HttpGet("/student/getstudent")]
            public object GetStudentName()
            {
                var userName = HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "N/A";
                var value = new
                {
                    name = "Raj"
                };
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

5. Program.cs
   [Click to open Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9RJn.png)

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CORS", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44459");
        });
    });
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddNegotiate();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
    }
    
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseCors("CORS");
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;
    
    app.Run();
```

I appreciate your solutions guys.
Thanks in advance

I have tried the multiple ways but none of them helped.

Comment: Please include your code-snippets as snippets in your question and avoid using images.

Comment: This is not an acceptable way to ask a question.  Post your code *as text* *here*

Comment: @akseli  Sorry, I am a newbie. Now I added the Code-Snippets. Kindly give some workarounds for this. Thanks.

Comment: @possum Sorry man, Now I added it. Kindly give some suggestions for this. Thanks.